# If I have a suggestion in general or would like to suggest a modification or an alternative use, can I email directly to the correspondent?

Tags: publications, etiquette, email, correspondence

With the availability of journal articles and online technology, how can I suggest an alternative use or a modification to the method reported on a webpage or journal article? The obvious route is emailing the correspondent, but would my email ever be looked at? Being a stranger to the webpage owner or corresponding author, shall I stack my credentials to impress the email receiver? I am sending the email as a public person, so I am afraid that my email message is going to be overlooked.

In terms of contents, they are about syntheses of chemicals and engineering.

Comment: As you noted, if it's a journal article, you can always email the corresponding author. I've always received replies when I've sent such emails, though I'm sending from my chemistry dept. email address, which probably helps. I would recommend putting something like "Comment on [insert article title]", or "Comment on your article in [insert journal title] about [insert brief summary of subject]". Either should get their attention. If you're emailing the author in English, I'd strongly recommend having a friend who is fluent in English edit your email prior to sending. I'm afraid that something

Comment: sent in broken English, like what you used in your post, is less likely to be taken seriously. And if you aren't an expert in the field, it would be beneficial if it could be reviewed by a local expert prior to sending, to ensure that what you think is an improvement really is one. If you have credentials, there's nothing wrong w/ starting with a brief intro., e.g., "I'm a chemical engineer with a speciality in W.   I currently oversee process control for X at company Y in location Z"

Comment: Finally, I'd recommend keeping the body of the email relatively short —no one wants to read a book from a stranger. If you want to give details, you can include them in an attachment (a well-organized attachment, with a summary at the beginning).

Comment: Did you also mean the following: if I am emailing as a person in the public -- without briefing my credentials but showing my understanding of the contents, my email is less likely to be taken seriously because I did not state my industry accepted status?

Comment: You won't know till you try. If you get past email filters etc, one problem is that if you approach someone with a *good* new idea they will have to determine how to proceed. Make sure you state your intentions and what you want out of the deal.

Comment: @theorist, I suggest you rewrite your comments as an answer.

Comment: @theorist. The OP's post is competently written and understandable. It hardly is in "broken English."

Comment: @Neithea Starting with the very first sentence, I was distracted by the obvious errors in grammar and construction—and I'm at least somewhat representative of the type of audience s/he is trying to reach. They are so obvious that I noticed them before I even began to consider the content.   That's the *last* thing you want to have when trying to present yourself as a sophisticated thinker whose ideas are worth considering. Specifically, I'm referring to the missing article, and that "journal article" and "technology" don't have parallel meanings. It should instead be something like: "With the

Comment: online availability of journal articles and other technical publications, how can I suggest a modification, or alternative use, for the methods reported in them?"  I'll add that I'm by no means casting aspersions on the OP. My best 2nd language is French, and I suspect the OP's English is better than my French. It's simply that one wants to put one's best foot forward, and to do that the OP needs a native (or highly fluent) English speaker to edit her or his email before it's sent (assuming it's being sent in English).

Comment: I'd apply the same guidance to myself: There's no way I'd send an introductory email in my broken French. I'd first have a native (or highly fluent) French speaker review and edit it.  Once the relationship is established, and the interchanges become more casual, 2nd-language errors are typically no longer an issue (so long as the two parties can understand each other).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can email the corresponding author. They may or may not receive or read your email, but there isn't much you can do about it.

No, you do not need to stack credentials. Even mentioning them at all, especially in the beginning of your email, probably makes it more likely it will be thrown away than read. You will sound like a crazy person if you mention all sorts of credentials. It's fine to have a brief signature at the end of your email; my professional signature has my name, degree, and work contact information.

They probably won't take your advice, and you shouldn't wait for or expect a response. Papers are published so that *everyone else can use the contents*. The person publishing a paper doesn't own or have responsibility for all the subsequent steps that might be taken. Someone else (including yourself) is free to make that modification and publish their own paper or use it for their own devices.

To have the best chance of having some positive impact, write directly and *concisely*. Spend far more time revising your message than writing it initially: make it as short and simple as you can. A brief greeting of praise is fine: "I was enjoying reading your paper (title)..." is enough. A paragraph of how much you admire their work is far, far too much.

Write from a serious email source; .edu is probably ideal, but if you aren't affiliated with a university you probably don't have an .edu address. Hopefully you have a professional email you'd use for resumes and such, rather than "spudbuster69@sketchydomain.co". Use an informative but brief title.